# Symfony2 QueryBuilder Group by and sum

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with a key field and a an expenses field.

I want to group by key and sum the expenses but when i do that the query result I get is an array with only the total field (alias of the expenses sym).

I need to get the whole entity like a normal select with qb.

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->addSelect('SUM(s.expenses) as total')
            ->addSelect('s')
            ->groupBy('s.keyval')
            ->getQuery();
    $soins = $query->getResult();
```

any idea? 
thanks

Comment: found the solution.
if any1 has the same problem here is how I accessed it.
in twig, I pass the variable $soins as soins

     {% for soin in soins %}
    {{soin.total}}
    {{soin.0.name}}
        //...
     {% endfor %}

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can help you

```
$sql = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('SUM(s.expenses) AS total')
        ->groupBy('s.keyval')
        ;

return $sql->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```